# EventHandler for Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I'm having an error when defining event click and function "select answer". I think it comes from JS

Console error:
"[Vue warn]: Property or method 'selectAnswer' is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
(found in )"

"[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event 'click': got undefined

(found in )"

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="main">Quiz app in Vue</h1>
<div id="question">
  <div id="function">
  <div class="user-role">
      <div class="question current">
        <transition name="slide-fade" mode="out-in">
          <div :key="questions[currentQuestion].question" :class="{'deactivate': answered == questions.length}">
           <h2>{{  questions[currentQuestion].question }}</h2>
      
 <div class="answers">
 <span v-for="(answer, index) in questions[currentQuestion].answers" :key="index" v-bind:data-index="index" @click="selectAnswer">{{ answer }}</span>
           </div>
          </div>
        </transition>
         <div class="next-question">
           <button class="next-btn" disabled>{{ currentQuestion < (questions.length -1) ? 'Next' : 'Result!' }}</button>      
         </div>
      </div>
    
    <div class="result">
      <div class="success"></div>
      <h2>You have successfully finished the quiz, and your score is:</h2>
      <h1 :class="[(Number(((correctAnswers / questions.length) *100)).toFixed(2) >= 50) ? 'green' : 'red']">{{ Number(((correctAnswers / questions.length) *100)).toFixed(2) }}%</h1>
      <small><b>{{ correctAnswers }}</b>Correct, <b>{{ wrongAnswers }}</b>Wrong</small>
      <button class="close">close</button>
      <button class="show-wrong-ones"
              v-show="wrongAnswers > 0"
              @click="showWrongQuestion = true">Wrong answers</button>
    </div>
  </div>
    
   <div class="wrong-questions">
     <h2 v-if="wrongQuestions.length > 1">Your wrong Questions</h2>
     <h2 v-else-if="wrongQuestions.length == 1">Your wrong Question</h2>
     <div class="wrong-one" v-for="question in wrongQuestions">
       <h3>{{ question.question }}</h3>
       <div class="answers-container">
         <span class="selected">{{ question.answers[question.selected] }}</span>
         <span class="correct">{{ question.answers[question.correct_answer] }}</span>
       </div>
     </div>
     
     <button id="return-to-result">Show my result</button>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
Vue.component ("function",{
  data: function ()
  {  
  },
  method: {
    selectAnswer: function(a) {
       var choice = a.currentChoice,
          answers = document.querySelectorAll('.answers span'),
          nextBtn = document.querySelector('.nextbtn');
      //? : -> Tenary Operator
      answers.forEach(answer => {
        answer.contains('selected') ? answer.remove('selected') : '';
      }); 
      choice.classList.add('selected'); 
      this.questions[this.currentQuestion].selected = choice.dataset.index;
 nextBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
      
    },
    calculateResult: (questions) => {
      var correct;  
      for(var i=0; i< questions.length; i++) {
        this.questions[i].selected == questions[i].correct ?  correct++ : '';
      }
    }
  }, 
   mounted() {
    var nextBtn = this.$el.querySelector('.next-btn'),
         answers = this.$el.querySelectorAll('.answers span'),
        questionsLength = this.questions.length,
        result = this.$el.querySelector('.result'),
        question = this.$el.querySelector('.question'),
        closeResult = this.$el.querySelector('.result button.close'),
        wrongQuestions = this.$el.querySelector('.wrong-questions'),
        showMyResults = this.$el.querySelector('#return-to-result');
          
    nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.answered < this.questions.length ? this.answered++ : '';
      if(!nextBtn.hasAttribute('disabled') && this.currentQuestion < (questionsLength -1)) {    
        this.currentQuestion++;
        answers.forEach(answer => {    answer.classList.contains('selected') ? answer.classList.remove('selected') : '';
  });
    nextBtn.setAttribute('disabled', '');    
      } else if(this.currentQuestion >= (questionsLength -1)) {
        
        this.questions.forEach( (question) => {
          if(question.selected == question.correct_answer && question.sense ==0) {
            
            this.correctAnswers++;
            question.sense = 1;
            
          } else if(question.selected != question.correct_answer && question.sense ==0) {
            
            this.wrongAnswers++;
            question.sense = 1;
            let temp = {};
            temp.answers = question.answers;
            temp.question = question.question;
            temp.correct_answer = question.correct_answer;
            temp.selected = question.selected;
            
            this.wrongQuestions.push(temp);
          }
        });
    result.classList.add('active');
        question.classList.add('blur');
      }
    }); 
     closeResult.addEventListener('click', () => {
      result.classList.remove('active');
      question.classList.remove('blur');
    });
     
  }, 
})

new Vue ({
  el: "#question",
  data() {
    return {
       questions: [
            {
            question: 'What is the capital of Ukrain ?',
            answers: [
                'Kyiv',
                '   Kabul',
                '   Buenos Aires',
                '   Praia'
            ],
            correct_answer: 0,
            selected: null,
            sense: 0
            },
            {
            question: 'When was Queen Elizabeth II death ?',
            answers: [
                '11/09/2022',
                '08/09/2022',
                '12/08/2022',
                '07/09/2022'
            ],
            correct_answer: 1,
            selected: null,
            sense: 0
            },
         {
            question: 'How many bones are there in human body?',
            answers: [
                '206',
                '186',
                '209',
                '190'
            ],
            correct_answer: 0,
            selected: null,
            sense: 0
            },
         {
            question: 'Who were the 30th president of ?',
            answers: [
                'Julia Eileen Gillard',
                'John Winston Howard ',
                ' Scott John Morrison ',
                'Anthony Albanese,'
            ],
            correct_answer: 2,
            selected: null,
            sense: 0
            },
         {
            question: 'What is the biggest continent?',
            answers: [
                'Oceania',
                'Europe',
                'Asia',
                'Africa'
            ],
            correct_answer: 2,
            selected: null,
            sense: 0
            }
        ],
      showWrongQuestion: false,
      wrongQuestions: [],
      temp: [],
      currentQuestion: 0,
      answered: 0,
      wrongAnswers: 0,
      correctAnswers: 0,
    }
  }, 
});
```

Comment: Seems like your code contains pieces of jQuery-style code. Normally (in most situations) you don't need to call `querySelector` or `addEventListener` or `setAttribute` - all of these can be defined declaratively in the template. Also, it's not safe to name your component `function` - a PascalCase multiple words name is recommended, e.g. `QuizApp`. Your components also do not define/refer to a template. Normally, if you're not using SFC your components must either specify the template as String or refer to the ID of a HTML `template` tag.

Comment: Yeah, use template refs as told above. Also, the correct wording is `methods` and not `method`.

Comment: Is there any way that I can fix this without using template?

Comment: You will get a far easier time with template refs. Why do you not want to use it here?